# Parsing error: Expression or comma expected while calling localStorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have this query:

```
export const getPosts = async () => {
    try {
        const posts = await JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem('Posts') || "{}")
        return posts
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}
```

And i'm calling it inside a functional component like this:

```
  const [ posts, setPosts ] = useState<Posts[]>()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts().then((res) => {
      setPosts(res)
    }) //HERE
  }, [])
```

Pretty basic, i don't see anything wrong but compile doesn't agree with me.

`Line 40:4:  Parsing error: Expression or comma expected`

Any hint?

Posts from `localStorage`:

```
"[{"title":"Chocolate Pistachio Cheesecake","body":"This recipe is for a reduced-fat cheesecake made with chocolate wafer cookies, pistachios, avocado, and Greek-style yogurt. The crust is made by pulsing chocolate wafer cookies, pistachios, and sugar in a food processor, and then pressing the mixture into the bottom of a springform pan. The filling is made by blending pistachios, cream cheese, avocado, yogurt, cornstarch, and sugar in a large bowl, and then adding egg whites, almond extract, and a pinch of salt. The cheesecake is then baked and cooled before being topped with a mousse made from whipping cream, powdered sugar, vanilla, and yogurt. The cheesecake is chilled for at least 4 hours before serving and garnished with additional whipped topping and pistachios.","comments":[{"author":"John Doe","content":"Nothing like a good workout to set the tone for the day. Keep up the great work! #motivation #fitnessgoals"},{"author":"Jane Smith","content":"This is another comment on the post."}],"likes":[{"author":"Brad Pit"}]},{"title":"Example post Title","body":"This is the body of the example post. It can contain any text.","comments":[{"author":"John Doe","content":"This is a comment on the post."},{"author":"Jane Smith","content":"This is another comment on the post."}],"likes":[{"author":"Tom Holland"}]}]"
```

Comment: remove the question mark after localStorage. What is the point of doing `?.getItem('xyz')`? The `getItem` function will always be present.
Also, where is line 40?

Comment: Thx. Removed but error still.

Comment: Where is line 40?

Comment: try to validate your JSON [here](https://jsonlint.com) should be invalid

Comment: Can you post your `Posts` from LocalStorage?

Comment: @AhmedSbai the json if valid

Comment: what is the use of async await in JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem('Posts') || "{}")??

Comment: @BuildThough dunno aways deal with localStorage assyncronous. Always worked, still worked excepets by this wier error.

Comment: For the best practise use {} inside useState({})

Comment: you got a parsing error, see my answer below

Comment: rgument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Posts[] | (() => Posts[])'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type '() => Posts[]'.
    Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(): Posts[]'. If i use {}

Answer (score 0):

what is the use of async await in JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem('Posts') || "{}")??
use like this as

```
 const getPostsFromStorage = () => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Posts'));
};
```

and then use it like
const posts = getPostsFromStorage() || ""

Comment: The function is ok, it's working.

Comment: I mean accessing json directly from localstorage assigns null so use at first check whether the post is null or not then if not null then only parse then it wouldn't give error

Comment: [eslint] 
src\components\GridComponent.tsx
  Line 40:4:  Parsing error: Expression or comma expected

Same error anyway

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i moved the file from `./src`to `./src/components` and the error went away. Don't know why.